# Extract alpha letters between a pipe and japanese character, and replace with space with comma

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have some data that looks like this in a dataframe:

```
Japanese
--------
明日|Adverb の|Case 天気|Weather は|Case なんですか
```

Using Pandas, I am looking for a way to return this in a new column

```
Tag
------
Adverb, Case, Weather
```

So far I have been able to use

```
df['Tag'] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ')
```

to get

```
Tag
------
Adverb Case Weather
```

but when I run

```
df['Tag'] = df['Tag'].str.replace(' ', ',')
```

I get

```
Tag
------
,,,,Adverb,,,Case,,,,Weather,,,Case,,,,,,
```

I think I'm supposed to use str.extract instead of replace, but i also get an error message in that case.

Comment: Try `df['Tag'] = df['Japanese'].str.extractall(r'([A-Za-z]+)').drop_duplicates().apply(', '.join)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `pandas.Series.str.findall`

```
s = df.Japanese.str.findall('(?i)[a-z]+')
pd.Series([', '.join({*x}) for x in s], s.index)

0    Adverb, Weather, Case
dtype: object
```

---

#### Sorted

```
s = df.Japanese.str.findall('(?i)[a-z]+')
pd.Series([', '.join(sorted({*x})) for x in s], s.index)

0    Adverb, Case, Weather
dtype: object
```